ПолучитьСтруктуруХраненияБазыДанных() в 1С сервисе
Как передать результат выполнения ПолучитьСтруктуруХраненияБазыДанных() через HTTP-сервис в 1С? Или это можно как-то по-другому реализовать через запрос?
Проблема в том, что при сериализации данных в JSON возникает ошибка, что структура данного метода содержит данные неподходящих типов. Неужели каждый массив перебирать в структуре и преобразовывать все в строку?


Покажите, что там за структура. Покажите, что там за ошибка конкретно.

@CrazyElf показал

Ну в общем у вас там видимо есть не простые типы. Для них нужно будет писать функцию преобразования и передавать её при записи JSON и при чтении. https://wonderland.v8.1c.ru/blog/sredstva-raboty-s-json/ абзац "Функции преобразования и восстановления при сериализации".

Вручную перебирать не нужно будет, но для каждого из непростых типов в этой функции нужно будет сделать обработку.
